# Почему на сайте регулярка работает, а в grep не работает?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

Регулярное выражение на сайте находит что мне надо, а когда пытаюсь его использовать в grep то не находит ничего.
[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/nrqbPP/1) нас сайте regex101.com (там выставлен PCRE? что должно соответствовать синтаксису регулярок в rgep в случае с параметром `-P`)

grep запускал с разными параметрами вот примеры:

```
grep -a -E "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd[\s\S]*?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /home/user1/test1.txt

grep -a -P "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd[\s\S]*?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /home/user1/test1.txt
```

сама регулярка:`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd[\s\S]*?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`

текст-пример для поиска

```
какой-то ненужный текст неважно
ываотыволдаптфдп


2019-06-10   промежуточный нужный текст       : FDGHDSH:keywrd, промежуточный нужный текст

ещё какойто нужный текст
    .конец нужного текста

--------------кусок неподходящего---------------------------
2022-07-10   промежуточный  текст       : FDGHDSH:keynotwrd, промежуточный нужный текст

ещё какойто  текст
    .конец текста
-------------- конец куска неподходящего---------------------------

2022-08-10   промежуточный нужный текст       : FDGHDSH:keywrd, промежуточный нужный текст

ещё какойто нужный текст
    .конец нужного текста


2021-06-10   ненужный текст
какой-то ненужный текст неважно
ываотыволдаптфдп
```

что я выяснил: в обычной регулярке выражение `[\s\S]*` находит любые пробельные и непробельные символы, но в регулярках grep'а не работают слеши в квадратных скобках.
Попробовал использовать поиск через `.*`, но grep построчно обрабатывает и и регулярка `.*` спотыкается о перевод строки, попробовал grep с параметром `-z` чтобы игнорировал все переводы строк и представлял весь текст как одну строку - тоже не помогло, вот пример модифицированной команды `grep -a -z -P "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd.*[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /home/user1/test1.txt`  вообще ничего не находит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -z -o -P '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.*keywrd[\s\S]*?[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}' 2.txt
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: grep не находит ничего, а rg нет возможности установить

Comment: @andrey-m проверьте еще раз, если не работает то либо старая версия утилиты grep либо с файлом что-то нето

Comment: спасибо, короче дело было видимо в кодировке файла, на другом попробовал и заработало. Очуметь сколько времени убил, всё правильно делал, а оказывается ошибку совсем не там искал(

Comment: @andrey-m бывает и такое